# How would I generate and pass mouse input into another device?

Tags: python, windows, mouse, hardware

I am looking to generate mouse input from my computer and send it to another device via USB port. Software bridge solutions will not work because the receiving device can't install any software. I've seen people use a Logitech Unifying Receiver to accomplish this but my Google Fu' isn't strong enough to find any resources related to this. However any hardware solution would work.

Just a general point to the right direction is all I need.

Comment: I would suggest pywin32 for capturing mouse on windows and a ESP32 board for recieving it through wifi or bluetooth of it, and some libraries for ESP32 micropython to stimulate HID Mouse input to the other device. It is going to be very complex project.

Comment: Thank you! Would a Raspberry Pi with micropython work also? Coincidentally I ordered one a while back for a different project.

Comment: Most Probabbely, Yes. You can search up about HID libraries for raspberry pi.

Comment: for mouse control/tracking I would suggest using `pynput`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.